# Unable to Invoke partial views using node.js and angularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have my angularJS application which works perfectly when i browse it, i was trying to configure express but only the main page displays and on click of the hyperlinks i am loading partial views but the partial views is not being loaded.
I get connection refused error in the browser.

Folder structure is:

**app**
  --routes.js

**node_modules**

**public**

**js** --app.js

**views**
--1.html
--2.html
--3.html

index.html(Main Page)

server.js

**Server.js**

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
require('./app/routes')(app);
app.listen(port);   
exports = module.exports = app;
```

**routes.js**

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});

app.get('/:name', function (req, res) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.render('public/views/' + name + '.html');
});
```

**app.js**

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp',['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider

// home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/1.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .when('/nerds', {
        templateUrl: 'public/views/2.html',
        controller: 'NerdController'
    })

    .when('/geeks', {
        templateUrl: 'public/views/3.html',
        controller: 'GeekController'
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

} ]);
```

Please let me know what needs to be done to make it work.

Thanks,
Sajesh

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad...i replaced templateUrl: 'public/views/2.html' with templateUrl: 'views/2.html' and it started working